# No OAuth2.0 for Twitter on behalf of users?

Tags: twitter-oauth

It looks that Twitter does not support OAuth2.0 on behalf of users.
I feel it is weird that they does not support because "Application-only" Twitter supports OAuth2.0.

When I looked into the official site, the only value of "grant-type" is "client_credentials".
So, no "authorization_code".
This means Twitter does not provide yet for OAuth2.0 on behalf of users???

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Twitter does not support OAuth2.0 yet, apart from Application-only authentication. As far as I am aware there is no timeframe for Twitter to fully support OAuth2.0.